# subbasis and basis in topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying topology and stuck in this problem.
I want to ask help.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces. Let $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ be the set of all continuous
functions from $X$ to $Y$ . For a subset $K$ of $X$ and a subset $U$ of $Y$ , let
$$V(K,U) := \{f \in C(X, Y ) | f(K) \subset U\} $$
Consider the set
$$S = \{V (K, U) | K \text{ is a compact set in }X\text{ and }U \text{ is an open set in }Y \}$$

1. Is the set $S$ a subbasis?
2. Explain by an example why $S$ is not a basis.
   (The topology generated by $S$ on $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ is called the compact-open topology.)

thank you:)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Note that $\{x\}$ is a compact set for any $x \in X$. Do you know what condition you have to check for being a subbase?